# Nginix Proxy Manager - bad gateway 502 for localhost

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup proxy hosts for various applications running on docker.

But whenever I use `localhost` or `127.0.01` host then I have bad gateway error.

When I set host as machine ip address in my local network `192.168.x.x` then it works, but it requires from me allow opened ports on `ufw` and also I am assuming it produces unnecessary traffic in my local network.

What can causing this problem?